# Read Google Hangouts messages using Android

Tags: android, google-hangouts

I have an [app](http://code.google.com/p/a2dpvolume/) that reads out GTalk messages using TTS.  Google Hangouts replaced GTalk so now I need to integrate with Hangouts.  I finally got a content observer working which gets called when Hangouts gets a message.

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri
                    .parse("content://com.google.android.apps.babel.content.EsProvider/"),
                    "messages"), true, observer);
```

When the observer is called

```
        public void onChange(final boolean selfChange) {
        if (paused) {
            Toast.makeText(application, "paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        Cursor message = null;
        Cursor conversation = null;
        Cursor contact = null;
        //Toast.makeText(application, "getting messages", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            final String[] messageProjection = new String[] { "body",
                    "date", "type" };
            /*message = getContentResolver()
                    .query(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.providers.talk/"),
                            "messages"), messageProjection, "err_code = 0",
                            null, "date DESC");*/

            message = getContentResolver()
                    .query(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.apps.babel.content.EsProvider/"),
                            "messages"), messageProjection, "err_code = 0",
                            null, "date DESC");
            if (!message.moveToFirst()) {
                Toast.makeText(application, "no messages", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
```

I get a permission error.

```
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580): FATAL EXCEPTION: TalkThread
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.babel.content.EsProvider from ProcessRecord{413dcdb8 9580:a2dp.Vol/u0a10071} (pid=9580, uid=10071) that is not exported from uid 10005
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2545)
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4647)
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2054)
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1101)
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:356)
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
05-26 07:45:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at a2dp.Vol.service$TalkObserver.onChange(service.java:1724)
```

I also tried adding this permission to my manifest:

```
com.google.android.apps.babel.content.EsProvider.permission.READ_ONLY
```

I also found [this blog](http://mobilave.info/blog/2012/How_to_catch_notification_of_some_Android_applications.html) that described an approach to finding way to interface with data like this.

I am open to any methods that may get the message sender and text of the most recent message.  I have not found any good documentation on Android interfaces with the new Hangouts. This was a very nice feature with GTalk and I would like to get the same functionality with Hangouts.  Any clues, info, suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally decided to read the notifications using Accessibility Service.  This works for most apps pretty well.  For Hangouts it reads the first unread message from each sender but subsequent messages will only report the sender name followed by "n new messages".

The source code for my project is here: http://code.google.com/p/a2dpvolume/

Look at Access.java mostly.  This is the accessibility service for my app.  This page: http://code.google.com/p/a2dpvolume/wiki/Accessibility_Settings explains how my up uses it.

Comment: jroal, can you add more details on how to use the Accessibility Service ?

Comment: The details are at that link above: http://code.google.com/p/a2dpvolume/wiki/Accessibility_Settings